# Google sheets api 500 INTERNAL error Node Js

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

Hello i'm using sheets v4 in my nodejs application everything works good for the majority of users but for some users using the service they always get **INTERNAL** status error
what's the meaning of this status and how can i fix it.

here's the error message:

```
{"code":500,"message":"Internal error encountered.","status":"INTERNAL"}
```

here's my code:

```
getSpreadsheetValues(tokens, ssID, SheetName, range, callback){
    request({
        url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+ssID+'/values/'+SheetName+'!'+range+'?access_token='+tokens.access_token,
        method: 'GET'
    }, function(error, response, body){
            var body = JSON.parse(body)
            callback(body.error, body.error ? "":body);     

    });
}
```

Comment: A 500 is an internal server error.  If you're able to share, what spreadsheet ID are you getting this error with, and what's the exact URL you're using when you experience the error?

Comment: Hello Sam it's a client spreadsheet i can't access it but i just want to know what this error message means ! like UNAUTHENTICATED mean the user have to be authenticated

Comment: 500 INTERNAL means the Google Sheets server had an internal error.  If it the error is just when doing a GET, it's unlikely there's anything you can do to fix it.  I can try to poke at what's going wrong, but will need the spreadsheet ID to do that.

Comment: Hello again Sam thanks for your responses here spreadsheet ID and Sheet Name.
SsiD =            1bipMmo5uEEsHUFfnHXAFSoChj8hmAIr55Tqbu4awB9Y
sheetName = Réponses au formulaire 1

Comment: One more thing Sam the error appeared for these users when their admin deployed our application in their domain

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.  Can you consistently reproduce it?  If so, what is the exact URL (minus the access token) on which you're reproducing?

Comment: i will try to reproduce and let you know

Comment: Hello Sam i used same url with the user tokken and Spreadsheet id it works perfect for me but the user is getting the error INTERNAL, what can cause this issue is it a configuration in his g suite domaine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API has a default quota of 100 reads/day. After that it throws a meaningless error message such as Internal Error Encountered.  I suddenly encountered these errors, even though I didn't change any of my code [[github](https://github.com/cvonk/gas-sheets-projectrolealloc/blob/master/README.md)].

Answer (score 0):

You can put a 100 second delay every 100 requests.

[image: Usage limit]